# How can I change the number of columns in Gridster?

Tags: javascript, gridster

I have a a gridster based layout that will start with a set number of columns and a fixed number of tiles. Is there a way to change the number of columns once it has been set up? -- for example starting with 3 columns :

> (tile1 | tile2 | tile3 
>   tile4 | tile5 | tile6)

and changing it to a two column layout:

> (tile1 | tile2 
>   tile3 | tile4 
>   tile5 | tile6)

The change will be driven by user interaction.

I have tried to use something like:

```
gridster = $("#gridster-container").gridster({
   widget_margins: [30, 30],
   widget_base_dimensions : [ 200, 170 ],
   max_cols:numberOfColumns,
   avoid_overlapped_widgets: true
}).data('gridster');

// user interaction

gridster.options.max_rows = 2;

gridster.init();
```

but that does not seem to work...

I have tried manually changing the `data-row` and `data-col` values to the new positions, and called init() (and not called init).

I have even tried changing the gridster code adding

```
    // HACK
    if (max_cols && max_cols < this.cols) {
        this.cols = max_cols;
    }
```

to the method `fn.generate_grid_and_stylesheet` (just after the line:

```
    if (max_cols && max_cols >= min_cols && max_cols < this.cols) {
        this.cols = max_cols;
    }
```

).

I can get the tiles to move the the correct position using any of these options, but subsequent dragging behaviour is... odd.

I have set up a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qT6qr/)  to explain what I mean (please excuse the gridster.min.js in line at the top of the fidddle, I couldn't find a cdn that I could use for it...).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you get the resolution, can you tell me please

Answer (score 4):

I just spent a couple of hours and ran across [this piece of code](https://gist.github.com/OwlyCode/6421823).  I just put it in a .js file and did:

```
var gr = $(elem).gridster(options).data('gridster');

// update options and then call this at a later point:

gr.resize_widget_dimensions(options);
```

And then it just worked.

Here's the code:

```
(function($) {
    $.Gridster.generate_stylesheet = function(opts) {
        var styles = '';
        var max_size_x = this.options.max_size_x;
        var max_rows = 0;
        var max_cols = 0;
        var i;
        var rules;

        opts || (opts = {});
        opts.cols || (opts.cols = this.cols);
        opts.rows || (opts.rows = this.rows);
        opts.namespace || (opts.namespace = this.options.namespace);
        opts.widget_base_dimensions || (opts.widget_base_dimensions = this.options.widget_base_dimensions);
        opts.widget_margins || (opts.widget_margins = this.options.widget_margins);
        opts.min_widget_width = (opts.widget_margins[0] * 2) +
            opts.widget_base_dimensions[0];
        opts.min_widget_height = (opts.widget_margins[1] * 2) +
            opts.widget_base_dimensions[1];


        /* generate CSS styles for cols */
        for (i = opts.cols; i >= 0; i--) {
            styles += (opts.namespace + ' [data-col="'+ (i + 1) + '"] { left:' +
                ((i * opts.widget_base_dimensions[0]) +
                (i * opts.widget_margins[0]) +
                ((i + 1) * opts.widget_margins[0])) + 'px;} ');
        }

        /* generate CSS styles for rows */
        for (i = opts.rows; i >= 0; i--) {
            styles += (opts.namespace + ' [data-row="' + (i + 1) + '"] { top:' +
                ((i * opts.widget_base_dimensions[1]) +
                (i * opts.widget_margins[1]) +
                ((i + 1) * opts.widget_margins[1]) ) + 'px;} ');
        }

        for (var y = 1; y <= opts.rows; y++) {
            styles += (opts.namespace + ' [data-sizey="' + y + '"] { height:' +
                (y * opts.widget_base_dimensions[1] +
                (y - 1) * (opts.widget_margins[1] * 2)) + 'px;}');
        }

        for (var x = 1; x <= max_size_x; x++) {
            styles += (opts.namespace + ' [data-sizex="' + x + '"] { width:' +
                (x * opts.widget_base_dimensions[0] +
                (x - 1) * (opts.widget_margins[0] * 2)) + 'px;}');
        }

        return this.add_style_tag(styles);
    };

    $.Gridster.add_style_tag = function(css) {
        var d = document;
        var tag = d.createElement('style');

        tag.setAttribute('generated-from', 'gridster');

        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
        tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

        if (tag.styleSheet) {
            tag.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        } else {
            tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        }
        return this;
    };

    $.Gridster.resize_widget_dimensions = function(options) {
        if (options.widget_margins) {
            this.options.widget_margins = options.widget_margins;
        }

        if (options.widget_base_dimensions) {
             this.options.widget_base_dimensions = options.widget_base_dimensions;
        }

        this.min_widget_width  = (this.options.widget_margins[0] * 2) + this.options.widget_base_dimensions[0];
        this.min_widget_height = (this.options.widget_margins[1] * 2) + this.options.widget_base_dimensions[1];

        var serializedGrid = this.serialize();
        this.$widgets.each($.proxy(function(i, widget) {
            var $widget = $(widget);
            this.resize_widget($widget);
        }, this));

        this.generate_grid_and_stylesheet();
        this.get_widgets_from_DOM();
        this.set_dom_grid_height();

        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and was able to get it working through this approach:

```
var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
gridster.options.min_cols = 5; // Not necessarily required because of the following size changes, but I did it for clarity
gridster.options.widget_base_dimensions = [240, 400];
gridster.options.min_widget_width = 240;

// This section was for existing widgets. Apparently the code for drawing the droppable zones is based on the data stored in the widgets at creation time
for (var i = 0; i < gridster.$widgets.length; i++) {
    gridster.resize_widget($(gridster.$widgets[i]), 1, 1);
}

gridster.generate_grid_and_stylesheet();
```

Comment: Hey Chris, if I want to change the maximum colums from 5 to 3 on browser resize what I need to do, I have tried with gridster.options.max_cols = 3 ,but still I see 5 tiles per row, and I have used your code in $window.on(resize)